# Point of objects vs dynamically created objects?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, dynamic

I just heard this from my freind's interview. He was asked what the difference and point of created an object dynamically vs created it regularly.

Example:

```
Obj *test = new test();
```

vs

```
Obj test;
```

What is the difference and what is the point of dynamically creating the object versus creating an object? I know one difference could be that the dynamically created variable is on the heap while the other is on the stack, but any more, bigger differences?

Comment: frist you can free the dynamically created one.

Comment: `new test();// on heap` and `Obj test; //on stack`

Comment: Why the hell are people closing this as "too broad".  It's not broad at all.  It's a bad question, for sure - as OP has not made any attempt to research this matter.  But it's not "too broad".

Comment: Stroustroup just cried. Sorry.

Just read at least one book about C/C++. Or even one beginners C/C++ article in the internet.

@Moo-Juice I always thought stackoverflow exists to help people, not for doing anything for people. This question may be answered by just reading books/internet articles. It is not deserved to be here. It's not global problem, not special situation. I guess, all we can help here is advice some good book to read.

Comment: I disagree with all of the close votes so far. If anybody can find a duplicate (I can only find *similar* questions), it can be closed for that, but this question is neither too broad nor off-topic.

Comment: @sftrabbit asking for the point of automatic vs dynamic allocation requires a whole chapter of a book. So I think the question is too broad.

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't have a concept of a heap and a stack. Instead, what these two different types of allocation are about is *storage duration*:

- When you create an object with a block local declaration, it has *automatic* storage duration. Such an object will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.
- When you create an object with `new`, it has *dynamic* storage duration. Such an object will be destroyed when you manually `delete` it. You, the programmer, are responsible for making sure the object is destroyed.

You should always prefer to use automatic storage duration when you can. You only need dynamic storage duration when you need an object to stay alive between different scopes. If you do need dynamic storage duration, you should prefer to use smart pointers (like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`), which manage the lifetime of the dynamically allocate object for you. This will help you avoid memory leaks.

Comment: any citation to **C++ doesn't have a concept of a heap and a stack**

Comment: @Pilot The only mention of a stack in the standard is in terms of "stack unwinding" when throwing exceptions - but that's just adopted terminology and doesn't necessarily mean that there is a stack. The heap isn't mentioned at all. (Obviously not counting `std::stack` and `make_heap`.)

Comment: `new()` internally call `malloc()`..and `malloc() == heap`.

Comment: @Pilot There's no citation for precisely that reason.

Comment: @Pilot `new` does not necessarily internally call `malloc`. The standard just says what it should do, not how it should do it. Whether it calls `malloc` is an implementation detail. Nonetheless, the C standard, in which `malloc` is defined, also makes absolutely no mention of the heap. So no, `malloc() != heap`.

Comment: @Pilot: Why are you making stuff up, and stating it as fact? Or are you just repeating what you heard from dubious sources?

Comment: @Pilot, `new` doesn't internally call `malloc`. _Some_ implementations of `new` - i.e., excluding excluding placement new, some custom (client-defined) implementations and so on - _may_ call `malloc` internally, depending on what the library implementers decide. It is in no way mandated by the standard though.

Comment: Here is [reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_opnt.cc?view=markup).@BenjaminLindley

Comment: @Pilot That is an implementation of `operator new`. I never said that it *can't* use `malloc`, just that it doesn't necessarily have to. The standard doesn't require it to. And if it did, it doesn't change the fact that `malloc` also doesn't have any concept of a heap. It just allocates memory.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is lifetime of the object: stack objects have it controlled automatically, while for heap objects it is controller manually. All other differences are results of this one.